# AngularJS Get Method Not Work

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs-http

I have an angular application, and I am trying to get a list of users from the server. I ran into an issue. I have page call CurrentUsers. If CurrentUsers method returns a Json Object, the entire object is display on the page regardless of what I do in the app controller and html page. If the method return a view, it does not display anything. However, I can hard code the json object in the cotroller, and it will work fine. 
As a result, I created another method to return the json object. I made a call to that method, but it never reached the server. Your help will be very much appreciated.

**The CurrentUsers Method returning a JSON Object, the entire json object display on the screen regardless**

```
 [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult CurrentUsers()
    {
        List<Users> currentUser = new List<Users>()
        {
            new Users{ UserName = "JDoe", Professor="SSmith", Course = "English1"},
            new Users{ UserName = "ADan", Professor="SDhor", Course = "Science"},
            new Users{ UserName = "ADes", Professor="SCarry", Course = "Religion101"},
            new Users{ UserName = "DJay", Professor="SCrowe", Course = "Teaching101"},
            new Users{ UserName = "MAnne", Professor="TRow", Course = "PreCalc"},
        };
        return Json(new { Ok = true, data= currentUser });
       // return View();
    }
```

**If the above method return a View, I can modify the controller as 
    shown below, and I will see the appropriate Information**

```
Registration.controller('CurrentUsersController', function ($scope, $http) {
 $scope.currentUsers = [{ "Professor": "SSmith", "UserName": "JDoe", "Course": "English1" }, { "Professor": "SDhor", "UserName": "ADan", "Course": "Science" }, { "Professor": "SCarry", "UserName": "ADes", "Course": "Religion101" }]
});
```

**I  modified the controller to use a service and created the method below to read the Current Users so that the view can simply return a View(). However, I have not been able to get the 'GET'to work.**

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetUsers()
    {
        List<Users> currentUser = new List<Users>()
        {
            new Users{ UserName = "JDoe", Professor="SSmith", Course = "English1"},
            new Users{ UserName = "ADan", Professor="SDhor", Course = "Science"},
            new Users{ UserName = "ADes", Professor="SCarry", Course = "Religion101"},
            new Users{ UserName = "DJay", Professor="SCrowe", Course = "Teaching101"},
            new Users{ UserName = "MAnne", Professor="TRow", Course = "PreCalc"},
        };
        return Json(new { Ok = true, data = currentUser , message = 
         "Success"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**the modify CurrentUsers Method to return a view**

```
  public ActionResult CurrentUsers()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

**My modify controller**

```
Registration.controller('CurrentUsersController', function ($scope, GetUSerService) {
    $scope.message = 'this is the Current User controller';
    $scope.currentUsers = [];
    var result = GetUSerService.getData()
                 .then(function (result) {
                     console.log('the result');
                     console.log(result.data);
                 });
});
```

**my service**

```
Registration.service('GetUSerService', function ($http,$q) {
    this.getData = function () {
        var deferredObject = $q.defer();
        $http.get('/Home/GetUsers').
        success(function (data) {
            console.log('service call data');
            console.log(data);
            deferredObject.resolve({ success: true, data : data.data });
        }).
        error(function () {
            deferredObject.resolve({ success: false, data : '' });
        });

        return deferredObject.promise;
    };
});
```

Updated 10/6 @5:50 
    @FernandoPinheiro answer works for me. The only thing is that the GetUsers action is being called twice.

[image]

**Updated 10/7**

I figured out why the post was being done twice. On my template, I had ng-app="Registration", and I  had ng-controller= "CurrentUsersController". Because I specified the controller name in the route provider, I did not need it to add it to the partial view. As soon as I removed it from the view, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your GetUserService is calling `$http.post('/Home/GetUsers')` instead of `$http.get('/Home/GetUsers')`.

Besides, shouldnt you set the Route attribute for the action ?

Comment: Of course! Sometimes we just need another pair of eyes... :)

Comment: I was playing around with the $http call which is the reason you see the post instead get. As far as the action, I did not set a route for it.

Comment: @FernandoPinheiro, your solution works. Changing only the $http.get did not work, but it works after adding the route to the route The one thing that I notice now is that the function GetUsers is being called twice now. I updated the question with a screen shot of the log file.

Comment: @JosianeFerice, is your controller being used in more than one place? The only way this is being called twice is if there is more than one instance of the controller on your view.

Comment: @FernandoPinheiro No, the controller is being called only once. Also, Sorry I shouldn't have edited the question. I am accepting your answer and close it. I am going to play around and figure out why it's posting twice.